# How to remove and append child with WebDriverIO?

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

I want to remove and later append a child to a parent element using browser.execute in WebDriverIO, but I keep getting the error **stale element reference: stale element not found**, however, keeping the reference to the removed child shouldn't cause this.

```js
const selector = '#unique-id';
let child = await browser.execute(selector => document.querySelector(selector).parentElement.parentElement, selector);
const parent = await browser.execute(c => c.parentElement, child);
child = await browser.execute((p,c) => p.removeChild(c), parent, child);
await browser.execute((p,c)=>p.appendChild(c), parent, child);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on a demo website. You could alter it a bit to make it work for you.

```js
  it('stack', async () => {
    await browser.url('https://www.saucedemo.com/');
    const parent = await $('.login_credentials_wrap-inner');
    const child = await $('.login_password');
    await child.waitForEnabled(5000);
    console.log(`Child Text: ${await child.getText()}`);
    const childSrc = await child.getHTML();
    console.log(`Child HTML: ${childSrc}`);
    console.log(`Step 0: ${await parent.getHTML()}`);
    await browser.execute((p) => {
      let chi = p.lastElementChild; // Read note at the end
      return chi.remove();
    }, parent);
    console.log(`Step 1: ${await parent.getHTML()}`);
    await browser.execute((c, k) => c.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', k), parent, childSrc); // Read note at the end
    console.log(`Step 2: ${await parent.getHTML()}`);
    expect(await $('.login_password').getText()).toContain('Password for all users:');
  });
```

Output on console:

```
[0-0] Child Text: Password for all users:
[0-0] secret_sauce
[0-0] Child HTML: <div class="login_password"><h4>Password for all users:</h4>secret_sauce</div>
[0-0] Step 0: <div class="login_credentials_wrap-inner"><div id="login_credentials" class="login_credentials"><h4>Accepted usernames are:</h4>standard_user<br>locked_out_user<br>problem_user<br>performance_glitch_user<br></div><div class="login_password"><h4>Password for all users:</h4>secret_sauce</div></div>
[0-0] Step 1: <div class="login_credentials_wrap-inner"><div id="login_credentials" class="login_credentials"><h4>Accepted usernames are:</h4>standard_user<br>locked_out_user<br>problem_user<br>performance_glitch_user<br></div></div>
[0-0] Step 2: <div class="login_credentials_wrap-inner"><div id="login_credentials" class="login_credentials"><h4>Accepted usernames are:</h4>standard_user<br>locked_out_user<br>problem_user<br>performance_glitch_user<br></div><div class="login_password"><h4>Password for all users:</h4>secret_sauce</div></div>
```

Note: Based on the order of your element, you have to modify the code. You can read about `insertAdjacentHTML` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and about `lastElementChild` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild).

Comment: child.getHTML() doesn't exist in this context, child is now HTMLElement and appendChild expects a Node, not a string.

Comment: Is this site publicly available?

Comment: Nope, can I provide something else instead for code reproduction?

Comment: the value of childSrc? You can mask any values which can not be shared publicly.

Comment: The value of childSrc cannot be retrieved by `getHTML()`, because child is not a WebdriverIO Element anymore. However, calling `child.outerHTML` does the same thing. But what I meant in the comment above is that the method appendChild won't work with a string, it expects a Node.

Comment: @kali I was able to make it work on a demo site. See if this works for you.